# Using a action's result

Tags: ros, action, ros-kinetic, action-client

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello together,

together with another student, we have written a action client and server by using `actionlib/client/simple_action_client.h` and `actionlib/server/simple_action_server.h`.

At the terminal we can see the result correctly.

Now we would like to use result for further activities. For this the source file of the client contains:

```
actionlib::SimpleActionClient<manipulator::DetectionAction>::ResultConstPtr result = *(ac.getResult())
```

`ac` is our action client, `manipulator::DetectionAction` is the ActionSpecs from the header file.

We have already started several attempts, but still are unsuccessful.

The compiler error is

```
actionlib::SimpleActionClient<manipulator::DetectionAction>::ResultConstPtr is private.
```

We would really appreciate, if someone could help us.

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309975/using-a-action%27s-result/) by [waltejon](https://answers.ros.org/users/38851/waltejon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What should work is the following:

```
DetectionResultConstPtr result = ac.getResult();
```

A little bit of background:

With

```
actionlib::SimpleActionClient<manipulator::DetectionAction>::ResultConstPtr
```

you are trying to access a private typedef declared in `actionlib/action_defintion.h` and `actionlib/action_client.h`.
Also, `getResult` already returns a `ResultConstPtr`, so adding `*(ac....)` will not work as well.

As the action definitions are templated, and you want to get the result (which has nothing to do with the client itself), `DetectionResultConstPtr` is the way to go here.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [waltejon](https://answers.ros.org/users/38851/waltejon/) on 2018-12-10**:
Thank you for the support! Your answer is correct.

Now we have another error that can be seen in the picture above. We already inspected this [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/218695/unable-to-access-members-of-control_msgsfollowjointtrajectoryaction/)... Could you help us?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-12-10**:
If this question is solved, please mark the answer as correct by clicking on the check mark next to it. For a new question, please open a new one ;-)
You can cross-link using q#NUMBER (from the url) and mention people using @USERNAME.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-12-10**:
Now, that the image is there: please don't post images of terminal output. This is not searchable by search enginges and the URLs might go away.

Please add a new question, paste the terminal output, and format it using the preformatted text button (the ones with 010101) on it as source code.

**Comment by [waltejon](https://answers.ros.org/users/38851/waltejon/) on 2018-12-10**:
All right, thanks for the advice.

**Comment by [nimish](https://answers.ros.org/users/65058/nimish/) on 2020-12-09**:
It didn't work for me with `DetectionResultConstPtr result = ac.getResult();`
It needed the package name as well, so `manipulator::DetectionResultConstPtr result = ac.getResult();` as mentioned in [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/310345/using-a-actions-result-pt-2/)